# Mongodb - Handling insertMany unique constraint violation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm working with node and mongodb 5. I have a unique index added to the Parcel property of my collection. As I run the program while testing, I get:

```
MongoBulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: mydata.pima2 index: Parcel_1 dup key: { Parcel: "AARON" }
```

My code:

```
for (let j = 0; j < lastNameRecords.length; j++) {
        const ln = lastNameRecords[j].name;
        const recordsObj = { 'Parcel': ln, 'recordNum': 'TBD' };
        recordsArr.push(recordsObj);
    }

    console.log('number of records: ', recordsArr.length);
    try {
-->        const response = await collection.insertMany(recordsArr, { ordered: false });
        const updated = await collection.updateOne(result, { recordNum: 'ERD' });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
```

Th error is occurring at the line with the arrow above. Obviously as I test,  I am inserting multiple records , all of which have been previously inserted into the 'pima2' collection. How do I avoid causing an error or handle it so that I can move on to the next statement

Answer (score 0):

Your error is related to your constraint violation, so it's prevent the scenario of repeated Parcel data.

```
{ Parcel: "AARON" }
```

There's two options to you,

1. Basically you can remove this constraint if you really don't need it and the error may disappear
2. Validate if this value already exists in your collection, after that create a find query passing this Parcel value and check if this value already exists. So you can advice to the user that this value already exists.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for looking at this. 1) I need the constraint. 2) The value is in my collection. I'm not sure I understand what you mean in the rest of number 2. Can you explain more please?

Comment: If you need constraint, you need to check if the value already exists, because the constraint. So, your application must know what to do when you receive a data that already exists. I tried to explain how you can do that. Do you understand what I mean to say now?

Comment: Did you understand or do you think I need to update my example?